# Received two -1 but didn't make a comment

Tags: support, achievements-dialog

I received two -1 but I didn't make a comment to that question. How come?

The question in question is [What used the Linux memory? Low cache, low buffer, not a VM](https://superuser.com/questions/764876/what-used-the-linux-memory-low-cache-low-buffer-not-a-vm)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This got nothing to do with comments. You simply downvoted two answers on that question.

Comment: Ok, I found that in my votes. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You downvoted two answers in that question.

Downvoting answers cost you 1 rep. Downvoting questions do not cost any rep.